# Nodejs+socket.io with index.php instead of index.html

Tags: node.js, codeigniter

I have simple application using nodejs.My view file is php instead of html.There is issue regarding compiling the php file using :
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.php');It works well with html file but not with php file. Please help how to use php with nodejs.

Comment: You'd have to use the child_process module to run your PHP file with the PHP interpreter and capture the HTML that it generates.  You need to send HTML to the browser, not PHP.  This type of hybrid system is quite inefficient.   You should probably decide if you're going to use node.js or PHP as your back-end and then code entirely in that.  If you stick with node.js, you can use any one of dozens of template engines to help you render your HTML using node.js.

Answer (score 0):

The [**PHP-Express**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-express) is one nice module which will help you to achieve your requirement. It is compatible with Express versions 3 and 4.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by using **[PHP-Express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-express)**
App structure

```
├── app.js
├── package.json
└── views
    └── file.php
```

and in app.js

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var phpExpress = require('php-express')({
    binPath: 'php'
});
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
app.engine('php', phpExpress.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'php');

app.all(/.+\.php$/, phpExpress.router);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).send("Sorry can't find that!")
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

You don't need to render php, view engine phpExpress will take care of it.router will find appropriate path and serve php from your view folder.